# PongGame paddle moves but previously drawn paddle doesnt' erase

Tags: python, pygame

The left paddle works fine it moves up and down no problem. But the right is okay when I don't move but when I do it moves to the directions I coded to but doesn't erase the previously drawn location which in the end just draws a straight line. Trying to make my first ever game with no tutorial and I'm kind of stuck

Here's the code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 720
window = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height),0,0)

pygame.display.set_caption("PongGame")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#background
background = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/teamb/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myGame/background.png")

#paddle image
paddle = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/teamb/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myGame/paddle.png")
paddle_size = paddle.get_rect().size

#left paddle
left_paddle_width = paddle_size[0]
left_paddle_height = paddle_size[1]
left_paddle_xpos = 10
left_paddle_ypos = (screen_height/2 - left_paddle_height/2)

to_x = 0
to_y = 0

character_speed = 10

#right paddle
right_paddle_width = paddle_size[0]
right_paddle_height = paddle_size[1]
right_paddle_xpos = screen_width - right_paddle_width - 10
right_paddle_ypos = (screen_height/2 - left_paddle_height/2)

to_y_2 = 0
# ball
ball = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/teamb/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myGame/ball.png")
running = True
while running:
   dt = clock.tick(60)
   
   print("fps : " + str(clock.get_fps()))

   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         running = False
   #left paddle
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            to_y -= character_speed
         elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
             to_y += character_speed

      if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            to_y = 0
   #right paddle
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            to_y_2 -= character_speed
         elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
             to_y_2 += character_speed

      if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            to_y_2 = 0

   left_paddle_ypos += to_y
   right_paddle_ypos += to_y_2

   if left_paddle_ypos < 0:
      left_paddle_ypos =  0
   
   if left_paddle_ypos > screen_height - left_paddle_height:
      left_paddle_ypos = screen_height - left_paddle_height

   window.blit(background,(0,0))
   window.blit(paddle, (left_paddle_xpos,left_paddle_ypos))
   window.blit(paddle, (right_paddle_xpos, right_paddle_ypos))
   window.blit(ball, (640, 360))
   
   pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is redrawing your background on every movement:

`window.blit(background,(0,0))`

However, I suppose your background image is actually smaller than your play field, so you are not redrawing the background on that side. You can either make your background image larger, or draw it again using an offset, or even draw it stretched. The idea is cover the entire play field when you are drawing the background.

It is worth pointing out this is not necessarily the most optimized way to do that. Ideally, you would redraw only the parts that had changed, but this is way more complex. Drawing the entire background is an easy fix.

Comment: yes ur right the background image was smaller then the window by about 200 pixels

Answer (score 2):

Moste likely the background *Surface* (`background`) has a smaller width  than the display *Surface* (`window`).

Clear the display before drawing the scene:

```py
while running:
   # [...]

   window.fill(0) # <--- clear display

   window.blit(background,(0,0))
   window.blit(paddle, (left_paddle_xpos,left_paddle_ypos))
   window.blit(paddle, (right_paddle_xpos, right_paddle_ypos))
   window.blit(ball, (640, 360))
   
   pygame.display.update()
```

Or scale the background image by [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale):

```py
background = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/teamb/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/myGame/background.png")
background = pygame.transform.smoothscale(background, window.get_size())
```

Comment: thank you my background really was smaller then the window!